# tablesorter problems with JSP

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a one-page application whose only page is created through a JSP. It allows people to look up bibliographic information. Unfortunately there are some problems with JQuery tablesorter.

1. The main one is that the result page cannot be sorted, nor the header images are visible, but if you save the page locally then it becomes sortable.

You can check it [here](http://simtestprv.uab.es/sidon).

For those who visit the place you will see a secondary problem. The encoding.

Comment: Sorry, I've just found a solution, although I don't know if it's the best. Once the table has been loaded (each time the user asks for information) I reassign ,in the Ajax callbak, the 

$("#result").tablesorter();

Comment: Yes, that's how your supposed to use tablesorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#result").tablesorter();
```